# How to test a service with two dependencies

Tags: java, junit, mocking, mockito, junit5

I don't know how to test a service with Mockito if it has two dependencies and the second dependency should work with the result of the first.

To better describe my problem, I wrote a small application for this: https://github.com/MartinHein-dev/mockito-example

With http://localhost:8080/countries one gets the result of three countries from https://restcountries.com/

I would be very happy if you could show me how the unit tests for de.example.mockito.service.CountryService.class would look like.

It feels wrong to continue with the mocked result of this.restCountiesClient.findCountriesByCode(countryCodes) and use it as a parameter in this.countryMapper.map(restCountryList), whose result is also mocked.

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class CountryServiceTest {
    
    @Mock
    RestCountriesClient client;
    
    @Mock
    CountryMapper mapper;
    
    CountryService countryService;
    
    List<RestCountry> restCountryList;
    List<CountryDto> countryDtoList;
    
    final String COUNTRY_CODES = "pe,at";

    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() throws Exception {
        countryService = new CountryService(client, mapper);

        restCountryList = List.of(
                new RestCountry(new RestCountryName("Peru", "Republic of Peru")),
                new RestCountry(new RestCountryName("Austria", "Republic of Austria"))
                );
        
        countryDtoList = List.of(
                new CountryDto("Peru", "Republic of Peru"),
                new CountryDto("Austria", "Republic of Austria")
                );
    }


    @Test
    void getAllCountries() {
        given(client.findCountriesByCode(COUNTRY_CODES)).willReturn(restCountryList);
        given(mapper.map(restCountryList)).willReturn(countryDtoList);
        
        List<CountryDto> result = this.countryService.getAllCountries(COUNTRY_CODES);
        
        assertEquals(2, result.size());
        assertEquals("Peru", result.get(0).getCommonName());
        assertEquals("Republic of Peru", result.get(0).getOfficialName());
        assertEquals("Austria", result.get(1).getCommonName());
        assertEquals("Republic of Austria", result.get(1).getOfficialName());
    }
    
    @Test
    void getAllCountries2() {
        given(client.findCountriesByCode(COUNTRY_CODES)).willReturn(restCountryList);
        given(mapper.map(restCountryList)).willReturn(countryDtoList);
        
        List<CountryDto> result = this.countryService.getAllCountries2(COUNTRY_CODES);
        
        assertEquals(2, result.size());
        assertEquals("Peru", result.get(0).getCommonName());
        assertEquals("Republic of Peru", result.get(0).getOfficialName());
        assertEquals("Austria", result.get(1).getCommonName());
        assertEquals("Republic of Austria", result.get(1).getOfficialName());
    }

    @AfterEach
    void tearDown() throws Exception {
        reset(client, mapper);
    }
```

Updated tests (2):

```
    @Test
    void getAllCountries() {
        given(client.findCountriesByCode(COUNTRY_CODES)).willReturn(restCountryList);
        given(mapper.map(restCountryList)).willReturn(countryDtoList);
        
        this.countryService.getAllCountries(COUNTRY_CODES);
        
        verify(client, times(1)).findCountriesByCode(COUNTRY_CODES);
        verify(mapper, times(1)).map(restCountryList);
    }
    
    @Test
    void getAllCountries2() {
        given(client.findCountriesByCode(COUNTRY_CODES)).willReturn(restCountryList);
        given(mapper.map(restCountryList)).willReturn(countryDtoList);
        
        List<CountryDto> result = this.countryService.getAllCountries2(COUNTRY_CODES);
        
        assertEquals("Other Name", restCountryList.get(0).getName().getCommon());
        verify(client, times(1)).findCountriesByCode(COUNTRY_CODES);
        verify(mapper, times(1)).map(restCountryList);
    }
```

Comment: Please add a minimal code-example that reproduces the problem.

Comment: @Torben I have updated the repository and included the specific test case in the description of the question.

Comment: Why do you feel like it's wrong to do it this way?

Comment: @Tim For example, if I adjust the getAllCountries() method so that the name of an item is changed. Shouldn't the test fail then?- restCountryList.get(0).getName().setCommon("Other Name"); - I know why it doesn't fail, but shouldn't it, to make sure everything is correct?

Comment: I have updated the repository and the description. I now have two test methods and two methods in the CountryService. One method does not change the result (getAllCountries). The other (getAllCountries2) does not change the result of the restCountriesClient. Both test methods run successfully. Shouldn't the 'getAllCountries2()' test actually fail because the original restCountryList was changed?

Comment: There are several ways to check that restCountryList will not be changed during the operation. You could compare it to a deep copy or use some Unmodifiable-Wrapper from the JDK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are testing `getAllCountries` you are testing that the data flow works within the method, because the method itself doesn't do anything else but pass data between the dependencies. Therefore you do not need to set up populated objects for that method and you do not need to assert that the returned objects contain any particular populated data. You only need to verify that the expected (mocked) dependencies were called with the expected object references.

Testing the values you set up in th test belong to the unit test that target `CountryMapper`.

For `getAllCountries2` you would have to verify that the value in the test data has changed like you expect, but again no need to verify the values otherwise.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So you mean I only have to check if the methods of the respective mocks were called and in the second test check if the name was really changed? I have adjusted both tests under "Updated tests:". Can you please have a look if I have understood this correctly?

Comment: You don't want to verify with anyString and anyList. You want to verify that the exact object references you intended to use were actually used.

Comment: I have adapted the sample code again under "Updated tests (2)" and hope that it is correct. Thank you very much.

Comment: Does that mean I only test what should have changed, but not what should remain?
I could, for example, check whether "restCountryList" changes and if it does, say that the test failed. Only does it make sense to check if something changes even though I know it doesn't?

I hope you understand my problem

Comment: Do you know what I mean? I would be very interested in your opinion.

Comment: You're not doing black box testing so if your code does not do any modification, then testing for unwanted modification is IMO waste of time. Once you start adding code that modifies the data, then you can start adding checks that unwanted modifications were not made. Of course, the best way to guard against unwanted modifications is to just use objects that cannot be modified instead of relying on 100% test coverage.